# Is it correct to say "Saturday is weekend"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

According to some dictionaries, "**Saturday**" is both countable and uncountable, and "**Weekend**" is just countable.

we can say "*Saturday is my only day off.*" or "*Today is Saturday*" and "**Saturday**" here is uncountable.

My question is that

Is it possible "**weekend**" is uncountable?

Can we say "**Weekend are Saturday and Sunday**"?

or do we say "**A weekend are Saturday and Sunday**"?

Also, can we say "**Saturday is weekend**" which is technically incorrect?

Or, do we have to say "**Saturday is a day of a weekend**"?

Comment: **The weekend** (a particular part of every week) is Saturday and Sunday. "I like to relax at the weekend" (Americans say "on the weekend".) **A weekend** is a particular Saturday and Sunday - "... a weekend in August".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Is it possible "weekend" is uncountable?

"Weekend" is definitely a count noun, as you found in the dictionaries. We can easily precede it with a number: "one weekend", "two weekends", etc. There is no reason to believe that it generally behaves similarly to "Saturday". (For one thing, "Saturday" is a proper noun while "weekend" is a common noun.)

2. Can we say "Weekend are Saturday and Sunday"?

No. The subject ("weekend") is singular but the verb ("are") is plural, yielding an agreement error.

3. or do we say "A weekend are Saturday and Sunday"?

No, for the same reason.

4. Also, can we say "Saturday is weekend" which is technically incorrect?

No. As you note, it is technically incorrect.

5. Or, do we have to say "Saturday is a day of a weekend"?

This is correct, although it is not the most natural way of expressing this idea. Because the week has multiple parts and the weekend is one of those, I'd more likely say "Saturday is part of the weekend".